# Error when trying to import Tensorflow Datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am following this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras and am getting an error when trying to use tf.data.Dataset.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.data
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
# Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(32,)),
# Add another:
layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
# Add a softmax layer with 10 output units:
layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Instantiates a toy dataset instance:
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels))
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
dataset = dataset.repeat()

# Don't forget to specify `steps_per_epoch` when calling `fit` on a dataset.
model.fit(dataset, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=30)
```

I get this error:

```
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tutorial.py", line 19, in <module>
    dataset = tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels))
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

I have pip installed both Tensorflow and the Tensorflow-Datasets API. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Please check  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets to know about the usage and syntax of tf.data.Dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `data` and `labels` are undefined.
You can initialize `data` and `labels` by adding

```
data = tf.random_uniform([1000, 32])
labels = tf.random_uniform([1000, 10])
```

before `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels))`

Comment: You basically copied my answer below. What is your exact input to the OP's problem?

Comment: I used tensorflow instead of numpy.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to define your `data` and `labels` variables.

As the tutorial states:

```
data = np.random.random((1000, 32))
labels = np.random.random((1000, 10))
```